# How do I create/set up/use an EJB project with a web app project in TomEE Plus/Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, web-applications, ejb, apache-tomee

I am trying to use an EJB project with a web app project in TomEE Plus and Eclipse. I can use a no interface bean in the web app project but when I create a new EJB project, configure build path on the web app to include the EJB project, TomEE will not start.

I set TomEE to Use Tomcat Installation in the Server Locations pane of TomEE properties in Eclipse. If I don't, I cannot even access the EJB in the same package as the Servlet.

The code is trivial:

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.IOException;
// Package containing remote interface and bean implementation
// Remaining imports omitted
import beans.* ; 
@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    HelloSBNoI hb ;             // The bean located within this project (same package as servlet)

    @EJB
    HelloBeanRemote hbfejb ;    // The bean located in an ejb project

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
                   throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html"); ;
        response.getWriter( ).write("Hello From Servlet <br />");
        response.getWriter( ).write("Hello From EJB in same package" + hb.from( ) );
        response.getWriter( ).write("<br />Hello From EJB in different project" +
                                     hbfejb.sayHelloEJB( ) );
    }
}
```

And here's TomEE trying to start, but failing:

> Jul 21, 2014 1:24:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
>   SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/useremoteejb]]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/useremoteejb]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>       ... 7 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lbeans/HelloBeanRemote;

```
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:400)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBContextConfig.configureStart(OpenEJBContextConfig.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: beans.HelloBeanRemote
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.LazyStopWebappClassLoader.loadClass(LazyStopWebappClassLoader.java:143)
... 22 more
```

I've spent hours trying to figure out what seems like a simple configuration error!

Thanks in advance for your expert assistance

Answer (score 0):

Yeah yeah...

I haven't figured out how to get the web app to look into the ejb project but I exported the ejb project and copied the JAR file WEB-INF/lib.

So, it's half a loaf but workable for now.